# CMake not building a library when added as a subdirectory

Tags: c++, git, cmake, xgboost

I added the [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) library as a git submodule of my project and I'm trying to add it to cmake as a subdirectory. Unfortunately it's not working. A simple hello world project with the following CMakeLists.txt replicates the error that I'm getting.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2) 
project(foo)
add_subdirectory(xgboost)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} xgboost)
```

After building the library there is nothing in the *xgboost/lib* directory so I get the following error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 
'/Users/.../myproject/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib'
```

I think that the problem is generated in their CMakeLists file since they have two different targets. Maybe cmake is choosing the wrong target but I'm not familiar enough with cmake to figure it out. The following code is from xgboost's CMakeLists.

```
  # Executable
  add_executable(runxgboost $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objxgboost> src/cli_main.cc)
  set_target_properties(runxgboost PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME xgboost
  )
  set_output_directory(runxgboost ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(runxgboost ${LINK_LIBRARIES})

  # Shared library
  add_library(xgboost SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objxgboost>)
  target_link_libraries(xgboost ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
  set_output_directory(xgboost ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

  #Ensure these two targets do not build simultaneously, as they produce outputs with conflicting names
  add_dependencies(xgboost runxgboost)
```

My questions in order of importance are:

1. Is there any way to fix it without modifying xgboost's CMakeLists.txt file?
2. Is it reasonable to try to add xgboost to my project as a git submodule?
3. Is there any reason cmake is not instructing to build the library?

Note: There were several edits to this question since I tried to narrow down the problem and to provide more information.

Comment: Please let me know if you think the question is missing relevant parts of my CMakeLists file and I'll add them.

Comment: Weird, as you use a **target** with `target_link_libraries`, CMake should find the library file at any location. Can you provide exact error message about not finding the library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the error to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to build `xgboost` project standalone? If this doesn't work, then the problem in the project itself. Otherwise, something wrong with integration into your project, while `xgboost` *seems* to be ready for such integration. It could be that some code of your project overwrites directory with the library created. When debugging the problem, you may detect the branch in `CMakeLists.txt` which is executed by adding `message()` calls into it. From what I can see, it is better to use `add_subdirectory (xgboost)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I made a really simple project and I still get the same problem. I also changed it to `add_subdirectory (xgboost)`. Thanks for that advice. You can check it in the updated question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You were right. It's not building the library in standalone when using xcode as the generator. I'm still not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

(I would love to ask for few things beforehand in the comment section, but I have too low reputation to do so, so I will just give it a shot ;))

I have few suspects, and one of them is `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` of the submodule's root `CMakeLists.txt`. Although the paths are set properly when you run that `CMakeLists.txt` alone, `cmake` gets confused the moment you add it as your subdirectory. Have you looked into another directories for your output binaries?

First I would suggest testing this hypothesis, and then I would suggest writing similar, but separate `CMakeLists.txt` file for `xgboost` library, and then substitute it in the project temporarily. Unfortunately the `CMakeLists.txt` filename is hardcoded and there is no possibility to have two files of that kind in one directory; so it seems that the answer to *1)* is, that you rather have to change the file.

For the *2)*: as long as it does not require huge additional logic in your `CMakeLists.txt`, it makes sense. Other viable option is to create an `install` target, which you can use to install your `xgboost` library locally (using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)) variable), and then add the installation path to your `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the reason. I'm adding some extra info to the question to see if it helps.

Comment: I updated the question with a very minimalistic example.